# Windows Boot Configuration Data(BCD) Reader in Linux?

Tags: windows, bootloader

Is there any way in Linux to read Boot Configuration Data(BCD) used by Microsoft Windows Boot Manager?

Regards,

Comment: Not if he's looking for a library or code samples.

Comment: I guess we'd know if the question were a little less vague...

Comment: @paul: Actually i need to know in which partition OS(VISTA/W7) is installed?

Answer (score 2):

I've started writing a Python lib for manipulating the Windows BCD. Repo is available at [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/wodny/libbcd/overview).